# Newtonsoft.Json Parse Error

Tags: c#, json.net

I am trying to parse some JSON with the code below, but I am getting the error below... I added a default empty constructor, but the error persists.

```
content = Convert.ToString (content).Trim ();
result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyType> (content);
```

content variable is:

> { "status" : "success", "result" : { "identity_document" : { "number" : "xx", "type" : "02", "country_of_issue" : "ZA" }, "person" : { "surname" : "xx", "initials" : "xx", "driver_restrictions" : ["0", "0"], "date_of_birth" : "05/11/1939", "preferred_language" : "", "gender" : "FEMALE" }, "driving_license" : { "certificate_number" : "xx", "country_of_issue" : "ZA" }, "card" : { "issue_number" : "02", "date_valid_from" : "19/05/2001", "date_valid_until" : "19/05/2006" }, "professional_driving_permit" : "nil", "vehicle_classes" : [{ "code" : "EB", "vehicle_restriction" : "0", "first_issue_date" : "18/05/2001" }], "photo" : "xxx" } }

Error:

> Unable to find a constructor to use for type MyType. A class should
>   either have a default constructor, one constructor with arguments or a
>   constructor marked with the JsonConstructor attribute. Path 'status',
>   line 1, position 12.

```
public class MyType
{
  public string status { get; set; }
  public Result result { get; set; }

  [JsonConstructor]
  public MyType()
  { }

  public MyType(string aStatus, Result aResult) {
   this.status = aStatus;
   this.result = aResult;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the accessibility of your parameterless constructor? It would really help if you'd show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Have you tried adding a `[JsonConstructor]` attribute to your parameterless constructor like the error message suggests?

Comment: Agree with Jon. To troubleshot this we would need to see both the value of "content" and the MyType class.

Comment: if `content` is a string then what is the use of `Convert.ToString (content).` if not, then you are on the wrong track. (Shortly: What is *content*)

Comment: I updated the entry to show my code above. I tried adding [JsonConstructor] to the default parameterless constructor but still getting the issue.

Comment: content is a string and contain the JSON that am trying to parse.

Comment: @Lennie then I assume you made enough research and checked how your model should be by pasting your json to [this side](http://json2csharp.com/)

Comment: Yes i did use json2csharp to convert the JSON above into my model

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work fine for using the following [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) with the latest version of Json.Net ([6.0.5](https://json.codeplex.com/releases/view/132306)) and .NET 4.5.  Try running this code in your environment to see if it works.  It should.  If it does, try modifying it bit by bit until it more closely resembles your code.  Once it stops working, you've found the problem.  If the code does not work in your environment with no modifications, then it's something with your environment.  Perhaps an old version of Json.Net?

Fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/cAk11I

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string json = @"
            {
                ""status"": ""success"",
                ""result"": {
                    ""identity_document"": {
                        ""number"": ""xx"",
                        ""type"": ""02"",
                        ""country_of_issue"": ""ZA""
                    },
                    ""person"": {
                        ""surname"": ""xx"",
                        ""initials"": ""xx"",
                        ""driver_restrictions"": [
                            ""0"",
                            ""0""
                        ],
                        ""date_of_birth"": ""05/11/1939"",
                        ""preferred_language"": """",
                        ""gender"": ""FEMALE""
                    },
                    ""driving_license"": {
                        ""certificate_number"": ""xx"",
                        ""country_of_issue"": ""ZA""
                    },
                    ""card"": {
                        ""issue_number"": ""02"",
                        ""date_valid_from"": ""19/05/2001"",
                        ""date_valid_until"": ""19/05/2006""
                    },
                    ""professional_driving_permit"": ""nil"",
                    ""vehicle_classes"": [
                        {
                            ""code"": ""EB"",
                            ""vehicle_restriction"": ""0"",
                            ""first_issue_date"": ""18/05/2001""
                        }
                    ],
                    ""photo"": ""xxx""
                }
            }";

        var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyType>(json);

        Console.WriteLine("ID doc number: " + root.result.identity_document.number);
        Console.WriteLine("ID doc type: " + root.result.identity_document.type);
        Console.WriteLine("ID doc country: " + root.result.identity_document.country_of_issue);
        Console.WriteLine("person surname: " + root.result.person.surname);
        Console.WriteLine("person DOB: " + root.result.person.date_of_birth);
        Console.WriteLine("person gender: " + root.result.person.gender);
        Console.WriteLine("D.L. cert number: " + root.result.driving_license.certificate_number);
        Console.WriteLine("card valid from: " + root.result.card.date_valid_from);
        Console.WriteLine("card valid to: " + root.result.card.date_valid_until);
        Console.WriteLine("vehicle class code: " + root.result.vehicle_classes.First().code);
        Console.WriteLine("photo: " + root.result.photo);
    }
}

public class MyType
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public Result result { get; set; }

    [JsonConstructor]
    public MyType()
    { }

    public MyType(string aStatus, Result aResult)
    {
        this.status = aStatus;
        this.result = aResult;
    }
}

public class Result
{
    public IdentityDocument identity_document { get; set; }
    public Person person { get; set; }
    public DrivingLicense driving_license { get; set; }
    public Card card { get; set; }
    public string professional_driving_permit { get; set; }
    public List<VehicleClass> vehicle_classes { get; set; }
    public string photo { get; set; }
}

public class IdentityDocument
{
    public string number { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string country_of_issue { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public string surname { get; set; }
    public string initials { get; set; }
    public List<string> driver_restrictions { get; set; }
    public string date_of_birth { get; set; }
    public string preferred_language { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
}

public class DrivingLicense
{
    public string certificate_number { get; set; }
    public string country_of_issue { get; set; }
}

public class Card
{
    public string issue_number { get; set; }
    public string date_valid_from { get; set; }
    public string date_valid_until { get; set; }
}

public class VehicleClass
{
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string vehicle_restriction { get; set; }
    public string first_issue_date { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
ID doc number: xx
ID doc type: 02
ID doc country: ZA
person surname: xx
person DOB: 05/11/1939
person gender: FEMALE
D.L. cert number: xx
card valid from: 19/05/2001
card valid to: 19/05/2006
vehicle class code: EB
photo: xxx
```